# What is the fastest way to programatically install or update to the latest version a global package?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, version, npm-install

I have a `npx` script that will install/update globally a certain package to the latest version, if not already.

Running `npm i -g myPackage` to ensure the latest version takes too long. Looks like it will go over all the package dependencies and check their versions, even if the desired package is already at the latest version.

I want to do something like this, but programatically. I already use `execa` package for similar stuff and probably would suit it.:

- `npm list -g myPackage` to check for package instalation

if installed, check if it is updated

- `npm outdated -g myPackage`

if not installed or outdated,

- `npm i -g myPackage` to install/update it.

Is there any ready solution for it or a built-in way to do it via npm? Else, how can I check programatically the results of the two verifications above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I done it in TS, it's working. Not sure if it's the best way, but takes way less time than doing a `npm i -g myPackage`, if it's already updated:

```js
import execa from 'execa';

async function checkGlobalPackageUpdate(packageName: string): Promise<'notInstalled' | 'outdated' | 'updated'> {
  console.log(`Checking if ${packageName} is installed and updated...`);

  // Check if it's installed
  try {
    await execa('npm', ['list', '-g', packageName]);
  } catch {
    return 'notInstalled';
  }

  // Check if it's updated
  const result = await execa('npm', ['outdated', '-g', packageName]);
  const updated = result.stdout === '';
  return updated ? 'updated' : 'outdated';
}
```

If no better alternatives show up, I may create a simple npm/npx package to use it, with more configurations.